# Page not found 404 for media url, getting images name from database Django 3.0.1

Tags: python, django, django-urls

This is my project folders

[image: Project Folders]

I first decided to set my media url and my media root on my settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/portfoliopicture/'
```

On my admin side, I decided to give it an url pattern in local, since I tho while I am in local it wouldnt be able to get my URL *"I wasnt sure at all since on the documentation nothing was talking about url pattern"*

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have define my model this way.

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='portfoliopicture/')
```

And using the url to get the image,

```
src="{{ portfolio.image.url }}"
```

Inside my template html, this is how i call it, This issue I am getting is so weird, It's like it isnt able to find the url path..

This is the message error I am getting. coming from the network tab
[image]

I would like to understand. Why am I having this issue when the url seems to be defined. Is it an issue with the way I'm calling the folders? I am clearly missing something here.

[this happen when i add the prefix manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zHB5.png)

```
 src="portfoliopicture/{{ portfolio.image.url }}"
```

Comment: error shows that image `C:\....\yoooo.PNG` doesn't exist so first check if it exists on disk.

Comment: @furas I edited the folder picture it is there!

Comment: read error message again - it searchs in `C:\...\media\ ` but you have image in `C:\...\media\portfoliopicture\ `

Comment: you're right! Why? I clearly set the url to portfoliopicture ?! Thanks for finding the issue, but I dont understand

Comment: it uploads to subfodler but i'm not sure if it adds `portfoliopicture` to url automatically or you have to add it manually in `src="portfoliopicture/{{ portfolio.image.url }}"`

Comment: I edited again, that doesnt seems to work if i put manually...

Comment: or maybe you have to set `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` and it will get `portfoliopicture` from url to `c:\...`

Comment: I've tried this too, it doesn't work. This is really strange. The image does display if I put it directly on media/ but I really want it inside a sub-folder.

Answer (score 1):

i had similar problem my solution

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="myportfolio/{{ portfolio.image.url }}" alt="">
```